# Levenshtein Distance for 'Have' and 'Havee': How to get to 1

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I have two strings for which I am attempting to compute the Levenshtein Distance distance: 'have' and 'havee'. When I work through the distance matrix I get a score of 0, however I can see it [computed elsewhere as 1](http://www.let.rug.nl/%7Ekleiweg/lev/).

I have reproduced my matrix below. It is worth noting I was [utilising this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiqoA-yF-0M&ab_channel=BackToBackSWE) and their approach to the replace/insert/delete order of operations:
[image: Havee and have edit distance matrix]

However this is clearly not right, as we must delete the extra E in Havee to get to Have. I'm not sure how to insert the '1' as we are told to take the minimum of the 3 cells, which for the extraneous e is 1,2 and 0. Even though the characters match should we disregard the extra 'e'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last entry, the one in the lower righthand corner, you’ve not actually followed the algorithm presented in the tutorial video. *E* matches *E*, and if you treat those two *E*s as a match, the edit distance will be the distance between *HAV* and *HAVE*. That distance is already in the table, just up and to the left of the lower righthand corner, in the *V* column and the first *E* column: it’s $1$. Thus, the entry in the lower righthand corner should actually be $1$. In general, when you have a match, you’ll simply copy the distance in the cell one space up and to the left.

And now you have the correct answer: to get *HAVEE* from *HAVE* requires **one** insertion.

Alternatively, you can apply the [recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Definition):

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{lev}(\text{HAVE},\text{HAVEE})&=\operatorname{lev}(\text{AVE},\text{AVEE})\\
&=\operatorname{lev}(\text{VE},\text{VEE})\\
&=\operatorname{lev}(\text{E},\text{EE})\\
&=\operatorname{lev}(\epsilon,\text{E})\\
&=1+\operatorname{lev}(\epsilon,\epsilon)\\
&=1\,,
\end{align*}$$

where I use $\epsilon$ to stand for the empty string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So just to confirm when you say 'match' you are referring to the fact our two strings now match? In which case as you suggest once we reach HAV and HAVE we have our edit distance.

Comment: @Hemmed: I meant that when you’re filling in the table, and you come to a cell whose row and column letters are the same, you fill it with the number just above and to its left. You did this correctly every time except the last time: the cell at bottom right has row letter E and column letter E, so it should have been filled with the $1$ in the row E, column V cell.

Comment: Oh my thank you! I understand now, thank you again.

Comment: @Hemmed: You’re very welcome!